# How do I use texSubImage2D to show sprites in webgl?

Tags: textures, webgl, sprite-sheet

I can display my entire sprite (32x512) successfully with this call to gl.texImage2D:

`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);`

It's squished horizontally, like I expected, but it renders on the screen at least. I'm trying to only display the first 32x32 sprite in the sheet and I assumed that I could simply use gl.texSubImage2D to achieve this effect. I tried a simple replacement of texImage2D with texSubImage2D (with modified parameters) but I just get a black box on the screen. Here's the code I'm using:

`gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);`

Am I missing something about the implementation of texSubImage2D? Is there some other step I have to do? Or is texSubImage2D not the right way to do sprite sheets?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`texSubImage2D` is not the function you want. You're running into three problems:

1. `texSubImage2D` does not copy a subset of `image` into the GL texture. It copies the entirety of `image` on top of the GL texture at a given offset.
2. `texSubImage2D` can only modify existing texture data, and will mess up unless `texImage2D` has been called first for the GL texture.
3. The calling style you're using for `texSubImage2D` expects a pixel array instead of an `HTMLImageElement`.

There are four possible signatures for these methods:

```
// These two accept the normal HTMLImageElement, etc. for the last param.

texImage2D(enum target, int level,  enum internalformat, enum format,
  enum type, Object object);
texSubImage2D(enum target, int level, int xoffset, int yoffset,
  enum format, enum type, Object object);

// These two accept a Uint8Array[] of pixels as the last parameter, despite
// being documented as wanting an ImageData object. The only reason these
// have a width/height param is *because* they take a pixel array, and GL
// doesn't know how large the image is.

texImage2D(enum target, int level, enum internalformat, long width,
  long height, int border, enum format, enum type, Object pixels);
texSubImage2D(enum target, int level, int xoffset, int yoffset,
  long width, long height, enum format, enum type, Object pixels);
```

To create a texture using the first 32x32 pixels of your image, do something like this instead:

```
var spriteCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
spriteCanvas.width = 32;
spriteCanvas.height = 32;

var spriteContext = spriteCanvas.getContext('2d');
spriteContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteCanvas);
```

Comment: Note: I said that those take a `Uint8Array[]`. That's not entirely correct: they take a typed array, but the type depends on the value of the `type` param to the calls.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. I assumed that I would have to do it in GL itself but using standard HTML elements is way easier for me.

Comment: texSubImage2D should have been the right function, but webgl1 has an awkward API around glTexSubImage2D. Fortunately it's fixed in webgl2.